# Displaying multiple itemViews with the same model

Tags: javascript, marionette

**SOLVED**

I'm building a calendar/tasks management app with Backbone.Marionette. This app has several views, including a to-do list and a daily, weekly and monthly view.

Some tasks have periodicity (for example, a task could be due every friday) and have to be displayed several times in the same View (using the same itemView) in different cells.

```js
Daily.Content = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
itemView: Daily.Event,
template: "#content-daily",

appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
//Obtains an id to append the items
  var id = "#x";
  var otherId = "#y";
  // Appends the itemView
  collectionView.$(id).append(itemView.el);
  // A different itemView with the same model
  var item = new Daily.Event({model:itemView.model}).render();
  collectionView.$(otherId).append(item.el);

  }
},
```

Now the same model is displayed twice. Clicking in an itemView(Daily.Event) allows you to delete it.

```js
deleteEvent: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.trigger("event:delete", this.model); 
  },
```

There is a Daily.controller handling that, which works just fine with the original itemView, but doesn't work with the second one. I don't know if the problem is my way of instantiating a new view or I should do some kind of binding.

I basically want to achieve what this guy wanted: [Using Marionette CollectionView to create multiple views per item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891247/using-marionette-collectionview-to-create-multiple-views-per-item)

Any ideas?

Comment: Reading the anotated Marionette source code I've figured out it was necessary to do this: `this.addChildViewEventForwarding(item);` before appending the view.

That way you can add as much replicated itemViews as you need to.

Comment: you should add this as an answer and accept it :)